# create a temporary variable in db2/400 (v5R4) within a RUNSQLSTM source file member?

Tags: sql, variables, ibm-midrange, db2-400

Can I create a temporary variable in db2/400 (v5R4) within a RUNSQLSTM source file member?  Maybe something like this?

```
CREATE VARIABLE myVar1 INT DEFAULT (RAND() *100)    
CREATE VARIABLE myVar2 INT DEFAULT (RAND() *100)    
CREATE VARIABLE myVar3 INT DEFAULT (RAND() *100)    

INSERT INTO file1 VALUES(myVar1, myVar2, myVar3)
INSERT INTO file1 VALUES(myVar1, myVar2, myVar3)
etc...
```

The goal is to quickly generate some random test data. Example above is simplified.

Comment: RUNSQLSTM do I mean to say here.

Comment: maybe I can rig up a work around in RPG or REXX.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You might want to add `or replace` to the create command so you can run it over if necessary. Also note the semi-colons`;`, they are important. This actually creates a global variable in the schema. Here is what I tested.

```
CREATE or replace VARIABLE myVar1 INT DEFAULT (RAND() *100);
CREATE or replace VARIABLE myVar2 INT DEFAULT (RAND() *100);
CREATE or replace VARIABLE myVar3 INT DEFAULT (RAND() *100);

create or replace table file1 (
  field1 integer,
  field2 integer,
  field3 integer);

INSERT INTO file1 VALUES(myVar1, myVar2, myVar3);
INSERT INTO file1 VALUES(myVar1, myVar2, myVar3);
```

My results looked like this:

```
select * from file1;


field1  field2  field3
19      69      60
19      69      60
```

Comment: .                    
I don't think this will work at v5R4......                                                                                                                                 Position 11 Token VARIABLE was not valid. Valid tokens:     
VIEW ALIAS TABLE SCHEMA UNIQUE ENCODED.                     
Position 20 Token MYVAR1 was not valid. Valid tokens:       
VECTOR.                                                     
Position 27 Token INT was not valid. Valid tokens: INDEX.

Comment: Ah yes, v5r4 is very old (think Windows XP), I am testing on v7.1, and we are not going to be at this level much longer as it is going out of service soon. IBM has been putting a lot of effort into the DB since v5r4. There are likely several desirable features you just can't take advantage of.

Comment: We have 2 v7.3 boxes in basement, waiting for a few weeks of spare time. ha!

Comment: Full system save, restore.

Comment: DSPOBJD to OUTFILEs, java upgrades, Apache server config files?

Comment: Yea, if you have that, it will be some extra work. And the conversion from v5r4 to v6.1, you have to make sure all your programs are observable, and that third party solutions are compatible. Such a large jump, will take some time.

Comment: everything is observable.  Third party upgrades ordered.  So far issues with apache server config, iSeries Access for web replaced with HATS. Note to readers has lots of changes to java, outfiles, and APIS. Lots to test.